# Кодировка кириллицы в Facebook JSON файле

Tags: python, pandas, кодировка, кириллица

Пытаюсь написать в Python скрипт что бы проанализировать сообщения между собой и своей девушкой. Скачал JSON файл с Facebook и весь текст вот в таком формате:

```
'\u00d0\u00a5\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b'
```

Я ковырялся вот тут:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826787/decode-or-unescape-u00f0-u009f-u0091-u008d-to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799187/encoding-decoding-issue-with-facebook-json-messages-c-sharp-parsing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492533/encoding-in-messenger-json

Вот мой код:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

with open('messages/message_1.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

# delete junk metadata
clean = data['messages']

# turn into a dataframe and print info for reference
df = pd.DataFrame(clean)
print(df.info())

# convert dates from epoch to datetime
df['timestamp_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_ms']/1000, unit='s')

# decode ascii
df['content'] = df['content'].encode('latin1').decode('utf8')

print(df['content'])
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Подскажите пожалуйста куда смотреть и что читать? Ну или решение. Спасибо!

Edit: Вот пример JSON файла.

```
    {
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "John Doe",
      "timestamp_ms": 1578752475283,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00a5\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "John Doe",
      "timestamp_ms": 1578679368572,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00a5\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Jane Doe",
      "timestamp_ms": 1578678854387,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00a5\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d1\u008b",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе или выложить на файлообменник небольшой пример JSON файла?

Comment: Добавил пример в оригинальный вопрос.

Comment: А как вы получили этот JSON? Если сохраняли средствами Python, то можно было воспользоваться параметром `json.dump(..., ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: Сам JSON файл можно скачать с Facebook. Вот инструкция: https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992. Там будет zip архив с кучей разного, в том числе и все сообщения из мессенджера. Вот еще интересная статься: https://towardsdatascience.com/mapping-my-facebook-data-part-1-simple-nlp-98ce41f7f27d

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле я этот вопрос написал специально чтобы на него ответить. Я перерыл пол интернета и потерял кучу времени на чтение документации о кодировке. Если бы я нашел это простое решение еще вчера я бы был дико рад. Надеюсь это кому нибудь когда нибудь поможет.

```
df['content'] = df['content'].str.encode('latin1').str.decode('utf8')
```

Вот все что понадобилось что бы дать правильный результат.